# Git-Bash and WSL have a different directory structure

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, git-bash

So I'm currently in the process of configuring and setting up my WSL on my Windows 10 workstation so I can use some very useful command line tools on Windows. Now in both WSL and Git-Bash you have access to all drives and partitions and all the files on the PC (that your user has access to), but the paths are different. Let's say I have a `temp` directory located at with a few files in it

```
tree C:\Temp
C:\TEMP
├───tempfile1.txt
├───tempfile2.txt
└───tempfile3.txt
```

Then when I open Git-Bash (using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386657/how-to-add-a-open-git-bash-here-context-menu-to-the-windows-explorer) SO Q&A) in the `C:\Temp` directory run the `pwd` command I see the path as

```
/c/Temp
```

but weirdly enough when I run an `ls` command in `/` in Git-Bash I don't see a `c` directory and no `mnt` directory either.

Now to WSL, when I do `Open Linux Shell here` via the right-click context menu in the Windows Explorer and run `pwd` it shows the path as being

```
/mnt/c/Temp
```

So my question is this: What and where is the '/' directory in Windows? And are these just 2 different ways of "mocking" the root directory?

**Edit:**
Windows version: Windows 10 Enterprise Edition Version 1903 (Build 18362.267)
WSL Version: 1809 (Build 17763) (Newest release as of time of writing)

Comment: @Ramhound Just added the information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Git-Bash is a typical Windows program, and functions as such. It sees `C:\` as its root directory.

Your WSL however, is different. I'm not sure if it's a container or VM, but regardless, it is definitively not a typical Windows program.
It still runs on Windows, but anything you run in WSL, essentially, sees itself as running on Linux, not Windows. This makes it follow Linux standards, such as Linux's directory structure.

This means, it has its own root directory, which instead of `C:\`, is `/`. The location of this directory is somewhere in your AppData, and varies based on the version of WSL and whether you're using Ubuntu, OpenSUSE, or whatever else.

In Linux, drives are not given letters. They are given mount points. The root `/` for example is the mount point of your root partition- or folder, in the case of WSL. Not everything under `/` is the same drive. For example, on my laptop, `/home/` is on a separate partition.

`/mnt/` is a mount directory in the Linux file structure. It's meant for external stuff.

`/mnt/c/` is your `C:\`. It has to be like this because Linux doesn't give drives letters. This is the correct and most elegant way of accessing Windows files from WSL. This is why bash in WSL has a different location for your `C:\`.

Assuming you have the most common WSL distro (Ubuntu), your `/` should be here:

`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs`

If it's not there or you use a different distro, look here:

`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\`

But be warned, Linux handles file permissions very differently from Windows. Do not do anything in here using windows tools like the File Explorer. If you need to interact between OSs, do it from within WSL.

Comment: Ah thanks. I don't have Ubuntu installed as I personally prefer Debian, but my Debian install was located at `%LOCALDATA%\TheDebianProject.DebianGNULinux_76v4gfsz19hv4`. Also just a quick note: WSL actually runs a full "fat" Linux kernel under the hood, using [Pico Processes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/05/23/pico-process-overview/)

Comment: I see, I'd never heard of pico processes. Seems to work kind of similarly to virtualization. I'll have to look into it more later. I know Linux better than I know WSL, lol.

Comment: I think pico processes are a lot lower level and are spun up/ shut down like you would when working with threads. I'll also have a look into it later, as I know Windows a lot better than I know Linux. Although I can find my way around a terminal with ease at this point

Comment: WSL1 doesn't run a Linux kernel at all; it just emulates the kernel syscall interface -- somewhat comparable to Wine. Each program in WSL gets its own pico-process; they're like normal Windows processes except they don't receive [all the Win32-specific stuff](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/05/23/pico-process-overview/) upon creation, instead receiving the Linux-syscall shim. (However, WSL2 _will_ run a full HyperV-based VM with standard Linux kernel, and will not use those.)

Comment: So it's sort of like a mix of a container and Wine?

Comment: **WSL is not a virtual machine.  It also is nothing like WINE.**  " WSL actually runs a full "fat" Linux kernel" - The current version of WSL does NOT run the Linux kernel.  WSL 2 will run the Linux kernel.  You are using the current version of WSL, which does not, run the Linux kernel.  "Do not do anything in here using windows tools like the File Explorer." - Except 1903 WSL supports doing this.  (Please fix these two major technical mistakes in your answer)

Comment: So how would you describe how WSL works, @Ramhound? Also, the user is on 1809 WSL, not 1903 WSL. Although to be fair, I was unaware 1903 WSL was fine with this.

Comment: @udlp - They are using both based on the contents of their question.

Comment: After basically no time looking it up, [1903 WSL doesn't entirely support doing that](https://betanews.com/2019/02/16/access-linux-files-from-windows/). It's treated like a network resource, you still are definitely not supposed to access the AppData files for it directly. Also, I see how you could say the "don't go in there with file explorer" part as a mistake, but what else is a mistake? I explicitly say I don't know how WSL works internally, I never say it is, or is akin to, a VM, container, or Wine.

Comment: @Ramhound the contents of their question say they're on Windows 1903 and WSL 1809. They make no mention of having a WSL 1903 installation.

Comment: @udlp if you're interested in WSL insights, see my GitHub profile.

Comment: @udlp - I can't possibly be expected, to give you enough information about WSL, so you can correct your answer.  You would use File Explorer, if you were accessing WSL file system, as a network resource.  For instance, you incorrectly indicated that WSL, is not a Windows application.  However, your answer has potential, but improvements could be made.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean with the 'not a windows application' part. I can correct that. As for the WSL file explorer thing, then you should see how I'm correct in that. I'm only saying you should never access the WSL files in the AppData directory I link. That's significantly different from a network resource.

Answer (score 1):

simply use this command on your bash

```
cd //wsl.localhost/dir
```

i use this below command to get into htdocs in my lampp

```
cd //wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/opt/lampp/htdocs/
```

Answer (score 0):

The / folder for WSL is in
`C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Packages\some serial number for ubuntu installation`
and can also be found as a network resource in
`\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04` or similar depending on what Linux distro you installed with for WSL.

For git bash its located at `C:\Program Files\Git`

You can always find the real location of any folder by going into it typing `explorer.exe .` git bash and wsl will both translate the `.` path for you and pass it along to the windows applications you run.

That being said you shouldn't open files these emulated `/` folders via windows at applications as they can have trouble reading it properly esp with WSL ones.

These programs are emulating the Unix file system for you without creating a virtual machine with segregated cpu and memory allocations. They just share with windows like a normal application does.
(except in the case of WSLv2 which is running a full VM using windows 10 pro Hyper-V)

The `/c` or `/mnt/c` locations are network mounts very similar to mapping a network drive in windows to say `Z:` and pretending its a local disk.

GIT bash and WSL are mounting your windows root drives as if they are network resources. In Linux, you mount drive to a `/folder` because there is no such concept of a drive letter.

If you want you can tell WSL to mount the drives the same way that git bash does.

In wsl type edit the `/etc/wsl.conf` file

And add the following:

```
[automount]
root = /
```

Save the file and LOG OFF from Windows and back in again.

Now when you launch WSL it will have the same paths as git bash for your local hard drives.

Also, keep in mind that these are emulating the file system used by Linux operating systems but they don't do it perfectly and they don't do it the same way.

For example, Unix file systems have permissions on files, git bash will automatically detect what "SHOULD BE" and executable file and add the +x attribute. WSL does not do this very well usually just makes everything executable.